# Unexpected error when request some ip/domain

Tags: python-3.x, request

response = requests.get('https://211.125.129.193')

i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 485, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1915, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1647, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 996, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 394, in connect
    ssl_context=context,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 383, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 491, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError("bad handshake: %r" % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='211.125.129.193', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = requests.get('https://211.125.129.193')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='211.125.129.193', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

not only with this ip ,, and with this domain : https://asa-bangalore-3.adobe.com/

 this problem append when i use get request with any [Cisco ASA & Cisco Firepower] Service

Answer (score 0):

Your IP doesn't exist and thus cannot be operated on.

Running `ping https://211.125.129.193` in the terminal gives and unknown host error. Make sure you use the right IP/URL, and that it's valid by either pinging it or using:

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('url')
print(response.status_code)
```

You should get `200` if there were no errors.

Comment: no this error related requests ssl check and i am use requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', verify=False)
but this error still found

when ping 211.125.129.193 this is work ,,, not shoud use http with ping :)